# P(0.13 ≤ X ≤ 0.72 and 0.36 ≤ X ≤ 0.91 )

Tags: probability, statistics

To solve this problem I did P(A & B) = P(A) * P(B) which was .59 * .55 and I got .32 as my final answer but this is wrong. What am I doing wrong? Is there something I'm missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not dealing with independent events.
In particular, $(0.13 \le X \le 0.72$ and $0.36 \le X \le 0.91 ) = (0.36 \le X \le 0.72)$, so the probability of this event is $0.36$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why the answer is 0.36 and how I can tell if the events are independent or not?

Comment: Simply $0.72-0.36$!

Comment: But WHY is it that?

Comment: Why can't I use the formula I listed in my question?

Comment: Obviously this formula is correct (the event $X \in [0.13, 0.72] \cap [0.36, 0.91]$ IS the event $X \in [0.36, 0.72]$!), so your is not. The two events would be independent if and only if the probability of the intersection would be equal to the product of the probabilities, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{P}(A \textrm{ and } B )=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$ iff $A$ and $B$ are independent, which is not true in your problem.